# DB2 SQL - How to check if an employee reached age 70 years and 6 months in current year?

Tags: sql, db2

I want to fetch an employee who reaches age 70 years and 6 months in year. That is, he should reached 70 years and 6 months between 01/01 and 12/31 of current year. Please help.

My table has the employees date of birth, datatype DATE. Database system DB2.

Comment: What have you tried yet where have you failed? That is not too hard to figger that out yourself. You should also add to your question which database system you are using and which datatype for the birthday.

Comment: I've tried using this logic (&Y_BEG_0 - BRTH_DT) >=690600 AND (&Y_END_0 - A.BRTH_DT) <= 700630. Its DB2. Data type of bith date is DATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try step by step.

If person becomes 70.5 years old on 2013-01-01, then his birthday is 1942-07-01.
If person becomes 70.5 years old on 2013-12-31, then his birthday is 1943-06-30.

Calculate these values in your programming language.
Then

```
SELECT * FROM empleyees WHERE birstday >= '1942-07-01' AND birstday  <= '1943-06-30';
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need not just for year 2013 alone, If I run the query next year, I should get the correct output.

Comment: "Calculate these values in your programming language". It is just an algorithm. Of course use present year, not hardcoded values.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this,

(A.BRTH_DT BETWEEN (SUBSTR (CHAR(DATE(&CURRDATE) - 71          
YEARS),1,4)||'-07-01')                                             
AND (SUBSTR (CHAR(DATE(&CURRDATE) - 70 YEARS),1,4)||'-06-30')

And this worked!

Answer (score 1):

We know the employee will reach 70 years 6 months in this year when:

- The year of birth is 70 years before the current year and month of birth is no later than June
- OR the year of birth is 71 years before the current year and the month of birth is no earlier than July.

Therefore we must filter as such:

```
SELECT Name FROM Employees
WHERE DateOfBirth BETWEEN '7/1/' + CAST((YEAR(GETDATE())-71) AS varchar) AND '7/1/' + CAST((YEAR(GETDATE())-70) AS varchar)
```

Comment: What if his b'day is October, 71 years ago?  Won't he reach 70 1/2 in April of this year ?

Answer (score 0):

What RDBMS are you using.  The answer needs date functions, and each RDBMS uses its own proprietary date functions.

In SQL Server, you could

```
Select case When birthdate Between
    DateAdd(month, -6, Dateadd(year, -70, dateadd(dd, 1 + 
                   datediff(dd, 0, getdate())-datepart(dy,getdate()), 0)))
And DateAdd(month, 6, Dateadd(year, -70, dateadd(dd, 
                   datediff(dd, 0, getdate())-datepart(dy,getdate()), 0)))
```

Comment: ahhhh, sorry!  does DB2 have date functions to extract, from any given date, the date that is the june 30th 71 years prior, and the July 1st that was 70 years prior ?

Comment: We can use YEAR(), MONTH(), DAY() to get the Year/Month/Day in a given date.

Answer (score 0):

(A.BRTH_DT BETWEEN (SUBSTR (CHAR(DATE(&CURRDATE) - 71 YEARS),1,4)||'-07-01') AND (SUBSTR (CHAR(DATE(&CURRDATE) - 70 YEARS),1,4)||'-06-30')

This SQL worked to fetch the Age 70.5 employees. &CURRDATE refers to Current Date.